# uneven scene change delay in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I made and android 2d game in unity 5 with about 15 scenes and applied scene change script to buttons, I observe uneven delay of scene changing by onclick button, some scenes load quickly while other load after a short delay of about 1~2 seconds and some times 2~3 seconds, suggest what could be done.

Comment: what do you actually want?? Do want to remove the delay??

Comment: yes  I want all scenes load in equal time

Comment: mean it is impossible in personal edition?

Comment: yes but you can add an loading screen to show user.

Comment: loading time is dependent on what those scenes contain and what scripts are running on loading them. Loading screen is the safest bet. Or just disable all buttons and display a loading message if the user is meant to see the same UI after the scene is loaded.

Comment: done it by deleting some game objects, but why loading time depends on game objects?

Comment: Complexity of the scene would have a big impact on how long it takes to load - the engine has to instantiate all those objects, and aside from memory allocation the components attached to your objects can really slow things down (if you process a lot in your `Start()`/`Awake()`...well, doing that more times will naturally cause more of a delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accurate, but probably undesired answer:

## There is nothing you can really do about this

Unity scenese, when you load a new one, have to be deserialized from disk (they are **not** kept in memory!).  The larger the scene is (the more gameobjects, monobehaviours, etc. etc.) there are the longer this process is going to take.  Additionally, *each* MonoBehaviour script needs to be sent an `Awake()` and `Start()` invokation which [has some significant overhead](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/).

You can reduce the overhead by using fewer scripts with Awake and Start methods (calling the same logic under a different method signature from a single Main script), as well as fewer scripts overall (further centralizing your program), as well as compiling the game under `Fast But No Exceptions` and `.NET Subset` (neither of these are available for Editor running, however), both mentioned in the prior linked article.

It is also possible that Unity compiles out scenes in the Resources format (which is [clunky and slow](https://youtu.be/n-oZa4Fb12U)) and you may benefit from using [Asset Bundles](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) instead.

However you're still going to be bound by the load times between various scenes regardless of your optimization efforts (what few options exist). A complex scene will *always* take longer to transition to than a smaller one, there's no way around *that*.